# iOS unit testing button has action assigned

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I've got the following button written programmatically:

```
self.button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[self.button setTitle:@"Reverse String!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0];
self.button.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(reverseString:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

However, my unit test fails when I try to test:

```
-(void)testButtonActionAssigned
{
    XCTAssert([self.vc.button respondsToSelector:@selector(reverseString:)]);
}
```

I get a failed message saying:

> test failure: -[ViewControllerTests testButtonActionAssigned] failed:
>   (([self.vc.button respondsToSelector:@selector(reverseString:)]) is
>   true) failed

My setup method is called:

```
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    self.vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"THIS METHOD IS CALLED");
}
```

Is it to do with the simulator timing and startup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I was testing the wrong thing.

The code in the question isn't really testing the button has an action assigned. It's basically saying "does the view controller responds to this method" or "does the view controller have this method".

```
// this is saying "does the ViewController know about this method"
// rather than "is ViewController's button assigned method reverseString:"
XCTAssert([self.vc respondsToSelector:...]);
```

This means regardless of whether button has a selector assigned or not, as long as the method is defined, this assert is always true.

I verified it by commenting out the line of code:

```
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(reverseString:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and the test still passes, which isn't what I was trying to achieve.

The **proper test** should be:

```
-(void)testButtonActionAssigned
{
    [self.vc viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *arrSelectors = [self.vc.button actionsForTarget:self.vc forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    NSString *selector = nil;

    if(arrSelectors.count > 0)
    {
        selector = arrSelectors[0];
    }

    XCTAssert([selector isEqualToString:@"reverseString:"]);
}
```

Now after commenting out the line:

```
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(reverseString:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The test fails as expected :D

This proper test code fetches the selector from the button and checks to see if it indeed is the method called `reverseString:`

### EDIT

After B.S. answer, and confirming with Apple's documentation, a shorter version can be written as:

```
-(void)testButtonActionAssigned
{
    [self.vc viewDidLoad];

    NSString *selector = [[self.vc.button actionsForTarget:self.vc forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] firstObject];

    XCTAssert([selector isEqualToString:@"reverseString:"]);
}
```

I was originally worried that calling firstObject on an empty array would cause an app to crash but Apple's documentation has confirmed to me that firstObject is a property that returns nil if array is empty.

> The first object in the array. (read-only)
>
> Declaration @property(nonatomic, readonly) ObjectType firstObject
>
> Discussion If the array is empty, returns nil.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSArray/firstObject

Comment: I believe you will find this useful: http://qualitycoding.org/uiviewcontroller-tdd/

Comment: @JonReid hey Jon, yes I've already watched your TDD introductory videos back then :D With iOS app the unit testing only test logic and a lot of the things we do on iOS dev is UI. I got an app where you clear the search field and a bar graph, which has 6 bars, 6 labels, a floating percentage score, a table of results on the bottom, they "reset". Maybe the unit testing is for logic, i.e. getting the results for the bar, but whether the UI looks correct, unit test isn't part of that and that leaves a lot of room for errors, needs manual testing.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(reverseString:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

First line means that `reverseString:` method should be in your `ViewController` (which is specified by `target:` parameter and you pass `self` there). So you need to change test with just removing `.button`

```
 -(void)testButtonActionAssigned
    {
        XCTAssert([self.vc respondsToSelector:@selector(reverseString:)]);
    }
```

Here is small example which can be changed:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton new];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(doThat:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

NSString *selectorString = [[button actionsForTarget:self forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] firstObject];

SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString);

// so now you can check if target responds to selector
// BOOL responds = [self respondsToSelector:sel];

NSLog(@"%@", selectorString);
```

Comment: :) I feel like an idiot now...why didn't I see that? omg.. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, this doesn't seem right. At the moment, the view controller knows about the method but it doesn't mean my button actually has that method assigned. I've commented out the line where I assigned it to my button and the test still passes, so that verifies it. What's the proper way to test if a button has an action assigned to it?

Comment: B.S., that still isn't correct, I copied and pasted your new code, with a few minor adjustment to fit my setup. Commenting out the button action assignment in my button init code, the `[self respondsToSelect:sel];` test case still passes, which it shouldn't. My answer below fails when I comment out the button action assignment, which is what is suppose to happen. So I still believe the proper way is testing the selector string using `isEqualToString:` as it verify that not only is the button assigned a selector, it is also the intended selector.